# Ui guide lines for disabling controls?

Tags: gui-design, guidelines

In my application I am disabling some controls depending on some checkbox state .Basically the controls consists of textboxes and labels.Currently I am disabling only the textfield so I want to know according to ui guidelines is it required to disable both the text and label .It might be a dumb question but from last 1 day I am searching for the Ui guidelines for it.Till now I am unable to find any.Any Light on this will be appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common practice it's to disable only the field and not the label. Even if a field is disabled the user must be able to read its label. This is an example of Bootstrap UI

[image]

[Bootstrap Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

In this example, there is also a mouse indicator, when the user hovers a disabled field

Comment: Good answer, but who said it was a common/best practice?

Comment: @lineplay It is a consistent practice (which makes it common and perhaps best practice) to not disable the label since the way a user interacts with it hasn't changed unlike the input field.

Answer (score 5):

There are no hard and fast rules for this. It entirely depends on how "disabled" the control looks to the user.

In the link you provided to the bootstrap forms, it doesn't strike me as very obvious that some types of controls are disabled. The text entry and select menus are fine, but for the radio buttons and check boxes I can only be sure they are disabled by visually comparing them to the enabled versions. For these it wouldn't hurt to grey out the label a bit, to underscore the fact that it is disabled.

In windows, the label on a checkbox or radio button is considered part of the control, and gets disabled / greyed when the box / button does.

[image]